# split column with array into individual columns in spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to split the dataframe with single column to individual column. Mainly to get a tabular format.Raw data format is a json file from where i have filtered the final set.

Dataframe name: result

Dataframe schema: `result.printSchema()`

```
root
|-- results: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- 50th Percentile: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- 90th Percentile: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- 95th Percentile: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- 99th Percentile: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- Avg: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- Count: string (nullable = true)
```

Result output: `result.show()`

```
+--------------------+
|             results|
+--------------------+
|[[0.390000,1.600...|
+--------------------+

result.collect()
[Row(results=[Row(50th Percentile=u'0.390000', 90th Percentile=u'1.600000', 95th Percentile=u'1.000000', 99th Percentile=u'2.000000', Avg=u'10.108981', Count=u'12')])]
```

What i tried to:

```
result_d=result.withColumn('new_col', split(result.results, ',')[0])
```

got exception:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'cannot resolve \'split(json.`results`, ",")\' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires string type, however, \'json.`results`\' is of array<struct<50th Percentile:string,90th Percentile:string,95th Percentile:string,99th Percentile:string,Avg:string,Count:string>> type.;'
```

Tried to convert to pandas dataframe and then split:

```
p=result.toPandas()
```

And then tried to split the nested string to columns

```
p['col'].str.split(",")
```

but got a NaN output

```
0   NaN
```

I am new with spark.Guide the right approach to play with these type of transformation.

Comment: So, you just want an RDD/Dataframe where the inner `element`  is the row? Can you not map over the `results` and just get that object?

Comment: that also returning error

Comment: Which part returns an error?

Comment: map part... seems something wrong with data type.. getting same error... while trying to split.. the array

Comment: You shouldn't need to split anything. You want to `flatmap` transform the `results` array to simply access the `element` attribute

Comment: oh... how do i do that way.. any sample.. not much aware of transformations

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122621/discussion-between-d14-and-cricket-007).

Comment: I haven't tried, so it may not work, but you are welcome to find the documentation for the `flatmap` operator for examples